# End of every race, Who am I?

Tags: riddle

What is the beginning of eternity,
The end of time and space,
The beginning of every end,
And the end of every race?

Comment: If you copy riddles from other sources, please cite them.

Comment: Didn't we just have this with the letter M? P.SE is turning into Sesame Street...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution is the

> letter **E**

What is the beginning of eternity

> **E**ternity

The end of time and space

> tim**E** and spac**E**

The beginning of every end,

> **E**nd

And the end of every race.

> rac**E**